# Using tail command with ifstat/dstat returns weird results

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I want to get the current upload and download speed .

"ifstat 1 1" command always returns an upload speed higher than 0 .

OUTPUT 1:

```
       eth0
 KB/s in  KB/s out
    3.00      0.15
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
       eth0
 KB/s in  KB/s out
    1.12      0.15
```

OUTPUT 3:

```
       eth0
 KB/s in  KB/s out
    2.37      0.34
```

I'm only interested in the last line so if I use the tail command to get it, the upload speed is 0 most of the times.

ifstat 1 1 | tail -1

OUTPUT 1:

```
    3.37      0.12
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
    0.87      0.00
```

OUTPUT 3:

```
    3.18      0.00
```

OUTPUT 4:

```
    3.12      0.06
```

OUTPUT 5:

```
    0.94      0.00
```

I also tried this with dstat .

dstat -n --nocolor 1 1 | tail -1

OUTPUT 1:

```
1856B 1089B
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
3328B    0
```

Notice instead of 0B it displays just 0.

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: Yes, I only have SSH running. However only when i use tail command upload speed is 0.  If i don't use tail it's always greater than 0 .

Comment: I deleted my comment because I wasn't sure if it really makes sense. Can you try to run a download or something like that in background when running the command trough tail ?

Comment: try to put output in variable, `OUT=$(ifstat 1 1); echo "$OUT" | tail -1`. Sorry can't explain why.

Comment: I tried this while running a speed test and it returns good results .  Upload speed is higher then 0 .  I guess everything is ok when there is actual internet traffic beside SSH .

Comment: That's actually very interesting.

Comment: Dstat always returns 0, not 0B because it is zero it doesn't matter what unit it is in. It's still zero.